How to show the sequence converges in distribution

Given $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is a sequence of independent random variables
satisfying:  $$\mathbb{P}[X_n = 2^n] = \mathbb{P}[X_n = -2^n] =
 \frac{1}{2^n}, \mathbb{P}[X_n = 1] = \mathbb{P}[X_n = -1] =
 \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2^n}.$$ a) Prove that the sequence $(X_n)$
converges in distribution and find the limiting distribution.
b) Let
$Z_n = \dfrac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}$. Prove that $Z_n$ converges weakly to
the normal distribution.
$(S_n=X_1+X_2+...+X_n)$

For part a) my idea is to determine the limit the sequence $(X_n)$ then prove it converges in probability hence in distribution. But currently, I can't predict the limit of the sequence $(X_n)$ converging to. Could someone help me?
Also, any help for part b) I would be very grateful!
Note:
$(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ converges to $X$ in distribution if $\text{lim}F_{X_n(w)}=F_X(x)\quad\forall x\in C(F_X)$ (the set of continous points of $F_X(x)$).
$(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$  converges weakly to $X$ if $\text{lim}\mathbb{E}[f(X_n)]=\mathbb{E}[F(x)]\quad\forall f(x)\in C_b(\mathbb{R})$ (the set of continuous, bounded functions in $\mathbb{R}).$
Converge in probability implies converge in distribution, converge in distribution implies converge weakly

For part a) simply note that $\lim_n\mathbb P(X_n=1) =1/2$ and $\lim_n\mathbb P(X_n=-1) =1/2$. Since those two limits add up to 1, then...

@framago I don't get your point

what is $s_n$ here?

@Lavender I edited the problem. Thanks for your recommendation

Note that weak convergence and convergence in distribution are the same thing. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2763306/635046

@AlexNguyen I edited my answer to include part b). Also, feel free to ask any questions. I'll be glad to help you with this one!

a)
Note that
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb P(X_n=1) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb P(X_n=-1) = \frac12.$$
This suggests that our sequence converges in distribution to a Rademacher random variable $X$. To see that, use Lévy's continuity theorem.
The characteristic function of $X_n$ is
\begin{align}
\varphi_n(t)&=\mathbb E(e^{itX_n})=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}e^{itk}\mathbb P(X_n=k)\\&=\Bigl(\frac12-\frac{1}{2^n}\Bigr)(e^{it}+e^{-it})+\frac{1}{2^n}(e^{it2^n}+e^{-it2^n})\\&=\Bigl(1-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\Bigr)\cosh(it)+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\cosh(it2^n)\\&=\Bigl(1-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\Bigr)\cos(t)+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\cos(t2^n).
\end{align}
The last equality follows from Euler's formula.
The characteristic function of $X$ is
\begin{align}
\varphi(t)&=\mathbb E(e^{itX})\\&=e^{it}\,\mathbb P(X=1)+e^{-it}\,\mathbb P(X=-1)\\&=\frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2}\\&=\cosh(it)\\&=\cos(t).
\end{align}
Note that $\varphi_n(t)\to\varphi(t)$ pointwise.
Since the sequence of the characteristic functions converges pointwise to the characteristic function of a random variable, Lévy's continuity theorem guarantees that our sequence converges in distribution to that variable.
b) Since the $X_n$'s are not identically distributed, we can't apply the classical CLT. But we know from part a) that our sequence is someway "close" to a sequence of iid Rademacher random variables, to which the classical CLT applies.
Note that
$$X_n\overset{d}{=}Z_n+(2^n-1)Z_nY_n,$$
where $Z_n$ is a sequence of iid Rademacher random variables, and $Y_n$ is a sequence of independent $\mathrm{Ber}(1/2^{n-1})$ random variables which are also independent of the $Z_n$'s. In fact, we have that
\begin{align}
\mathbb P\bigl(Z_n+(2^n-1)Z_nY_n=\pm1\bigr)&=\mathbb P(Z_n=\pm1,Y_n=0)\\&=\mathbb P(Z_n=\pm1)\,\mathbb P(Y_n=0)\\&=\frac{1}{2}\Bigl(1-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\Bigr)\\&=\mathbb P (X_n=\pm1),
\end{align}
but also that
\begin{align}
\mathbb P\bigl(Z_n+(2^n-1)Z_nY_n=\pm2^n\bigr)&=\mathbb P(Z_n=\pm1,Y_n=1)\\&=\mathbb P(Z_n=\pm1)\,\mathbb P(Y_n=1)\\&=\frac{1}{2}\Bigl(\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\Bigr)\\&=\mathbb P (X_n=\pm2^n).
\end{align}
Write
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k\overset{d}{=}\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum_{k=1}^n Z_k + \frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum_{k=1}^n (2^k-1)Z_kY_k.$$
Note that $\mathbb E(Z_k)=0$ and $\mathrm{Var}(Z_k)=1$, hence using the classical CLT for iid sequences we get that the first term converges in distribution to a standard normal r.v. Next, we show that the second one converges to $0$ almost surely. Then, we will be done with our exercise, since the LHS and the RHS have the same didsitribution and the RHS converges in distribution to a standard normal r.v.
Since $\sum_n\mathbb P(Y_n=1)<\infty$, Borel-Cantelli lemma ensures that $\mathbb P\bigl(\limsup_n\{Y_n=1\}\bigr)=0$, i.e. the probability that $Y_k = 1$ infinitely often is $0$. Equivalently, there is a sure event $A$ such that, for all $\omega\in A$, $Y_k(w)$ is equal to 1 just a finite number of times. In symbols,
$$\forall \omega\in A, \:\exists N(\omega) : Y_k(\omega)=0, \:\forall k> N(\omega).$$
Thus, for all $\omega \in A$, we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum_{k=1}^n (2^k-1)Z_k(\omega)Y_k(\omega)\\=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum_{k=1}^{N(\omega)} (2^k-1)Z_k(\omega)Y_k(\omega)\\=0.$$
This finishes the proof since
$$\mathbb P\biggl(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum_{k=1}^n (2^k-1)Z_kY_k=0\biggr)\ge\mathbb P(A)=1.$$
